# removeFromSuperview not working - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Please see below code.  I am trying to remove the video subview from view when the 'done' button is pressed or video stops playing.  I show no errors in the code but the removeFromSubview method does not seem to be working.  I am not sure if my syntax is wrong or if it is something to do with having the movieplayer code within the IBAction method and the moviePlayBackDidFinish outside below the viewDidLoad.  Any advise much appreciated.  Thanks

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class VideoViewController: UIViewController {

var moviePlayer:MPMoviePlayerController!

@IBAction func videoLaunch(sender: AnyObject) {
playVideo()
}
func playVideo() {
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MyVideo", ofType:"mp4")
let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
if let player = moviePlayer {
player.view.frame = self.view.bounds
moviePlayer?.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Fullscreen
player.prepareToPlay()
self.view.addSubview(player.view)

}  
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
    self,
    selector: "moviePlayBackDidFinish:",
    name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification,
    object: moviePlayer)


func moviePlayBackDidFinish(notification: NSNotification){
    self.view.removeFromSuperview()
}



}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to remove `self.view` not `moviePlayer.view`.

Change your `moviePlayBackDidFinish` code to:

```
func moviePlayBackDidFinish(notification: NSNotification)
{
    if let player = moviePlayer
    {
      player.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Gets the following error; [CGC.VideoViewController moviePlayBackDidFinish:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd85b52ae60

Comment: @BenThomas: That's because you wrote that function inside viewDidLoad, move that to outside of that function and place it in your class

Comment: Thanks Midhun all works now.  Just have to work out how to make the Fwd and Rewind buttons now!